# Based on Acts 6:15, What type of Angel (ἀγγέλου) did Stephen's face look like?

Tags: acts, angels

Does the term "Angel" or "Angelou" (ἀγγέλου) used in **Acts 6:15**  mean Stephen's face looked like a כְּר֨וּב Keruv, or one of the שְׂרָפִ֨ים Serafim?

**Acts 6:8-15** [NASB]

> "[8] And Stephen, full of grace and power, was performing great wonders and signs among the people. [9] But some men from what was called the Synagogue of the Freedmen, including both Cyrenians and Alexandrians, and some from Cilicia and Asia, rose up and argued with Stephen. [10] But they were unable to cope with his wisdom and the Spirit by whom he was speaking. [11] Then they secretly induced men to say, “We have heard him speak blasphemous words against Moses and God.” [12] And they stirred up the people, the elders, and the scribes, and they came up to him and dragged him away, and brought him before the Council. [13] They put forward false witnesses who said, “This man does not stop speaking against this holy place and the Law; [14] for we have heard him say that this Nazarene, Jesus, will destroy this place and change the customs which Moses handed down to us.” **[15] And all who were sitting in the Council stared at him, and they saw his face, which was like the face of an angel.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Acts 6:8 And Stephen, full of **grace and power**, was performing great wonders and signs among the people. ...
>
> 15 And all who were sitting in the Council **stared** at him, and they saw his face, which was like the **face** of an angel.
> 7:1 Now the high priest said, “Are these things so?”
> 2 And Stephen said, “Listen to me, brothers and fathers!

Stephen was graceful and calm. His listeners were not awestruck. They weren't frightened by his appearance. It wasn't the kind that appeared in Matthew 28

> 1 After the Sabbath, at dawn on the first day of the week, Mary Magdalene and the other Mary went to look at the tomb.
>
> 2There was a violent earthquake, for an **angel of the Lord** came down from heaven and, going to the tomb, rolled back the stone and sat on it. 3His appearance was like lightning, and his clothes were white as snow. 4The guards were so **afraid** of him that they shook and became like **dead** men.

It wasn't the kind that appeared in Genesis 3:24

> So He drove the man out; and at the east of the Garden of Eden He stationed the **cherubim** and the **flaming** sword which turned every direction to guard the way to the tree of life.

It wasn't the kind that appeared in Isaiah 6:

> 1 In the year of King Uzziah’s death I saw the Lord sitting on a throne, lofty and exalted, with the train of His robe filling the temple. 2 **Seraphim** were standing above Him, each having six wings: with two each covered his face, and with two each covered his feet, and with two each flew.

Based on Acts 6:15, What type of Angel (ἀγγέλου) did Stephen's face look like?

The verse does not specify the exact type of angel. It is more generic and idiomatic. Stephen was filled with the Holy Spirit and grace. His face brightened with a radiance that reflected God's glory. I'd put more emphasis on the grace aspect and less on the awestruck aspect at this point.